# ntpdate wrong date

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntp, date, ntpdate

Hi all I have an ubuntu8 server where I have problems with date.
My current date (Europe/Rome) is 9:35
If I do `date` print me `11:12:34`
I have seen my ntp.conf is:

```
    server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
    server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
    server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
    server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
    restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
    restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
    restrict 127.0.0.1
    restrict ::1
    restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 modify notrap
```

if I stop and start ntpdate return me this:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

I set:

```
Europe
Rome
```

and print me

```
Current default timezone: 'Europe/Rome'
Local time is now:      Thu Mar 28 11:16:06 CET 2013.
Universal Time is now:  Thu Mar 28 10:16:06 UTC 2013.
```

If I do date print me

```
Thu Mar 28 11:16:25 CET 2013
```

I have tried this:

```
/etc/init.d/ntp stop
ntpdate it.pool.ntp.org
```

Print me:

```
no server suitable for synchronization found
```

if I Check this:

```
netstat -antltp | grep "LISTEN"

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3114/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3295/vsftpd
tcp        0      0 109.233.120.149:53      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2935/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2935/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2988/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3265/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2935/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2969/openvpn
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      2935/named
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2988/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      2935/named
```

How can I set the right date?
Thanks

Comment: what is displayed in your /etc/timezone? Is this also Europe/Rome ?

Comment: Yes is Europe/Rome @timmeyh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ntpd has some safety limits based on the size of the discrepancy between local time and network time. If the discrepancy is too big, ntpd won't update the time. So you better set the system time as correct as you can (after stopping ntpd) with:

> /etc/init.d/ntp stop
>
> date +%T -s "hh:mm:ss"
>
> /etc/init.d/ntp start

This should hopefully fix the problem

Comment: Alternatively, use the ntpdate command to set the time correct as far as NTP thinks, and then restart ntp. eg: sudo ntpdate -uv 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org

Comment: Return me error 28 Mar 11:35:10 ntpdate[3897]: ntpdate 4.2.4p4@1.1520-o Fri Dec  4 18:18:35 UTC 2009 (1)
28 Mar 11:35:15 ntpdate[3897]: no server suitable for synchronization found
@DanielLawson

Comment: No isn't correct return me again at the old wrong time @timmeyh

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri What does "ntpdate -u 3.debian.pool.ntp.org" returns?

Comment: @timmeyh return me"no server suitable for synchronization found"

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri can you ping your ntp servers which are in your ntp config file? If so, do a check with netstat that your port is open with 'netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN"'

Comment: As far as I know, `ntpdate` has its own config file - `/etc/default/ntpdate`

Comment: @timmeyh  have updated my question with netstat. And I ping the server inside my ntp file

Comment: @slimsuperhero my file was NTPDATE_USE_NTP_CONF=no I have changed to yes

Comment: Okay, then try to stop `ntp` daemon and `ntpdate-debian`.

Comment: return me "no server suitable for synchronization found" @slimsuperhero

Comment: Okay, try `ntpdate 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org`

Comment: @slimsuperhero same thing: "no server suitable for synchronization found"

Answer (score 0):

A "no server suitable for synchronization found" error typically occurs when a firewall blocks the traffic. Make sure port 123 is open to incoming udp traffic on your machine.

Regarding netstat, UDP is stateless so you don't expect to find anything if you `grep "LISTEN"`. And you don't expect to find any UDP connection with -t but no -u. Use `netstat -ul` or `netstat -uln` instead. Don't forget to restart your ntpd before you do that.